# Как пройтись по списку элементов в selenium?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

На странице получаю элементы. Хочу через foreach пройтись по ним и вытащить html.

```
var data = driver.ExecuteScript("return document.querySelectorAll(\"div[class^='item-info-root']\")");
```

Пытался так, но не работает

```
foreach (var o in data as IEnumerable)
{
    Console.WriteLine(o);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

попробуйте `FindElements`:

```
var collection = driver.FindElements(By.Xpath("//div[@class='item-info-root']"))
```

ну и далее

```
foreach(var o in collection as IWebElement)
{
    Console.WriteLine(o);
}
```